# developing for modularity & reusability: how to handle While True loops?

Tags: python, module, modularity

I've been playing around with the pybluez module recently to scan for nearby Bluetooth devices. What I want to do now is extend the program to also find nearby WiFi client devices.

The WiFi client scanner will have need to have a `While True` loop to continually monitor the airwaves. If I were to write this as a straight up, one file program, it would be easy.

```
import ...

while True:
    client = scan()
    print client['mac']
```

What I want, however, is to make this a module. I want to be able to reuse it later and, possible, have others use it too. What I can't figure out is how to handle the loop.

```
import mymodule

scan()
```

Assuming the first example code was 'mymodule', this program would simply print out the data to stdout. I would want to be able to use this data in my program instead of having the module print it out...

How should I code the module?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is going to be to have the scanner run on a separate thread from the main program. The module should have methods that start and stop the scanner, and another that returns the current access point list (using a lock to synchronize). See the [threading module](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html).

Answer (score 1):

How about something pretty straightforward like:

mymodule.py

```
import ...
def scanner():
    while True:
        client = scan()
        yield client['mac']
```

othermodule.py

```
import mymodule
for mac in mymodule.scanner():
    print mac
```

If you want something more useful than that, I'd also suggest a background thread as @kindall did.

Answer (score 1):

Two interfaces would be useful.

1. scan() itself, which returned a list of found devices, such that I could call it to get an instantaneous snapshot of available bluetooth.  It might take a max_seconds_to_search or a max_num_to_return parameter.
2. A "notify on found" function that accepted a callback.  For instance (maybe typos, i just wrote this off the cuff).

   ```
   def find_bluetooth(callback_func, time_to_search = 5.0):
     already_found = []
     start_time = time.clock()
     while 1: 
       if time.clock()-start_time > 5.0: break
       found = scan()
       for entry in found:
         if entry not in already_found:
           callback_func(entry)
           already_found.append(entry)
   ```

   which would be used by doing this:

   ```
   def my_callback(new_entry):
     print new_entry    # or something more interesting...


   find_bluetooth(my_callback)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question, you want `scan()` in a separate file, so that it can be reused later.

Create **utils.py**

```
def scan():
    # write code for scan here.
```

Create **WiFi.py**

```
import utils

def scan_wifi():
    while True:
        cli = utils.scan()
    ...
    return
```